# Could anyone please explain what the following code does and HOW it works?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

My teacher said it was javascript if that helps

```
function mystery(x) { 
  x--; 
  x|= x>> 1; 
  x|= x>> 2; 
  x|= x>> 4;
  x|= x>> 8; 
  x|= x>> 16; 
  x++; 
  return x; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it / stepping through it in a browser to see what happens?

Comment: `homework` tag is absolute

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer there was a java tag with the question

Comment: This is what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 3):

It finds the lowest power of two that is greater or equal to `x`. Alternately, everything after `x--` will find the lowest bit that is left of all the ones in `x-1`.

For example, if you have `x - 1` as

```
00010100111010100001010011101010
```

then `mystery(x)` will be

```
00100000000000000000000000000000
```

It first fills up all the zeroes that follow a one, by folding the ones to the right; after the first operation, every one will have one following it. Then we fold two-bit groups: every two ones will now become four. Then we fold four, then eight. Then we take out the big hammer, sixteen bits.

```
00010100111010100001000000001100  // x - 1
00011110111111110001100000001110  // after folding one bit
00011111111111111101111000001111  // after 2
00011111111111111111111111101111  // after 4
00011111111111111111111111111111  // after 8, and every step thereafter
```

Here, `x++` will switch all ones to zero, making one carry to the next column:

```
00100000000000000000000000000000  // after x++
```

The weird decrement at the start is so we catch `<=` instead of strict `<`. For example, if we start with

```
00000000000000000000000000000100  // x
00000000000000000000000000000011  // after x--
00000000000000000000000000000011  // after folding, unchanged - they're all ones anyway
00000000000000000000000000000100  // after x++
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
x>> 1;
```

- Shifts x in binary representation 1 bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off

`x|= x>> 1;`

- Performs a bitwise OR on the result of `x >> 1` with `x` and stores the result in `x`

Answer (score 1):

The function `mystery(x)`, gets the next highest power of 2 of a number `x`. The initial decrement statement (`x--`) makes the function returns the same value if the number is already a power of 2. `mystery(x)` will behave *interestingly* for signed integers when approaching `INT_MAX_VALUE`.

You could have derive this answer by graphing the function values for small values of `x`